# Mongodb: How to add a geospatial index to an existing database

Tags: python, mongodb, geospatial

I have an existing mongo db without proper geo-spatial format. Is it possible to add geo spatial indices to this existing db?

some details about the db

each document in the collection has the keys `lat` and `long` but not the specified `loc` parameter.

P.S. I am a newbie w.r.t. MongoDB. so am not sure what else to add in this question

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need what [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) terms a [2d index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/). To [build a 2d index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/), issue:

```
db.<collection>.ensureIndex( { <location field> : "2d" ,
                           <additional field> : <value> } ,
                         { <index-specification options> } )
```

To [query this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2d-index/), use:

```
db.<collection>.find( { <location field> :
                     { $geoWithin :
                        { $box|$polygon|$center : <coordinates>
                  } } } )
```

Leave a comment if this doesn't sort your problem.

Some more digging yields a page suggesting [combining longitude and latitude into one field](http://christiankvalheim.com/post/35293863731/the-wonderful-world-of-geo-spatial-indexes-in-mongodb), in other words something like this:

```
loc = [long, lat];
db.<collection>.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d" } );
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But seeing that I have two separate fields entitled ``lat`` and ``long`` should I do something like

``db.<collection>.ensureIndex({'lat': '2d', 'long': '2d'})``

Comment: You need to add a new field combining 'lat' and 'long' per my edit